# How to make a JSON Parser to parse elasticsearch mapping in java?

Tags: java, json

I wanted to parse this structure which is an elasticsearch filter:

```
{
"filter": {
   "name_synonyms_filter": {
     "synonym_path": "sample.txt",
     "type": "abc_synonym_filter"
    },
    "name_formatter": {
      "name": "name_formatter",
      "type": "abc_token_filter"
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how can I access individual filters without using key ("name_synonyms_filter" , etc) in java?

Comment: To verify: You really do have `"abc": {}` there, not `"abc": []`? Because what you have is not JSON, and if it's not JSON then you cannot parse it as such. You can either a) Manually fix the source to make it valid JSON, b) somehow fix the source programmatically (how and how difficult this is depends on the actual content  and the possible content the file has, c) write your own parser.

Comment: Also, which language are you using to process the data?

Comment: I see you updated the example again. While this is valid JSON, it's very uncommon to have multiple entries with the same key in an object, because most languages will simply take the last entry. Is that really what you have?

Comment: I updated the question this is what i have

Comment: So you edited it again. Now the question is what is the actual problem you are facing? The value of `abc` is just another object, like the whole JSON document is an object.  Do you know how to access objects? And again: which language you are using to process the data? And is your question really about **parsing** the JSON (converting from text to "native" value, which should work always the same way) or **accessing** the result of the parse process? If the latter you have to tell us what you are using to parse it, since results and APIs are different in every language.

Comment: I'll post another question having all the description

Comment: No, [edit] this question instead. You may want to have a look at [ask] first. The more information you provide, the easier it is for us to help you and the more likely it is that you get the solution that you are actually seeking.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: You still haven't said which language you are using to process the data.

Comment: I am using java

Answer (score 2):

your JSON was impropertly formatted.

Here it is fixed:

```
{
    "abc": [{
            "name": "somename"
        },
        {
            "name": "somename"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to parse it:

```
let x = JSON.parse({
    "abc": [{
            "name": "somename"
        },
        {
            "name": "somename"
        }
    ]
});

console.log(x);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: "abc" is still not a jsonarray it's like a json list so my question is how can i parse a json list ?

Comment: @TechnocratSid you added `{ }` instead of `[ ]`, again, this json is incorrect. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to see why.

Comment: FWIW, the OP didn't mention that they were using JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling JSON is a Javascript Serialized Object Notation, so I assumed he was using JS, either way the concept of manipulating JSON is the same.

Comment: @Moshe: JSON is used as general data exchange format, just like XML. The name doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @FelixKling, either way I can assist the OP with JSON parsing. From what I understand he has an object that contains many objects (of the same kind I assume) and he wants to iterate over them as if they were an array? Despite the language, it sounds like a type casting question

Comment: The question is unanswerable in its current state IMO.